# Загрузка связанных данных EF через generic метод

Tags: c#, entity-framework

В базе данных у меня хранится следующий класс. Каждый класс продукта имеет ссылку на категорию к которой принадлежит.

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Sale> Sales { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        Sales = new List<Sale>();
    }
}
```

Для загрузки продуктов из базы я использую следующую функцию.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{
    return db.Set<T>().ToList();
}
```

Проблема состоит в том, что при использовании Set я не могу загрузить связанные данные, такие как Категория. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Сделайте в контексте нормальные свойства `public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }` и не мучайтесь.

Answer (score 1):

Под рукой нет чистого EF. Есть только EF Core, поэтому детали возможно придётся подправить, но суть должна быть ясна.
Можно добавить дополнительное выражение, которое тоже передавать в качестве аргументов для загрузки данных, и в нём как раз использовать загрузку доп. зависимостей.
Получается что-то вроде такого

```
private static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>(Func<IQueryable<T>, DbSet<T>> postAction = null) where T : class {
    return (postAction?.Invoke(db.Set<T>()) ?? db.Set<T>()).ToList();
}
```

А сам вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
    var a = GetAll<Product>(m => m.Include(m => m.Category));
```

Ну а без зависимостей остаётся просто:

```
    var a = GetAll<Product>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно ли перебрать все продукты таким образом:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{
    var query = db.Set<T>();

    if (query.GetType() == typeof(IQueryable<Product>))
    {
        query = query.Include(c => (c as Product).Category);
    }

    if (query.GetType() == typeof(IQueryable<Product2>))
    {
        query = query.Include(c => (c as Product2).Category);
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: При таком подходе результат `query.Include` должен быть записан в переменную, иначе он ничего не даст. Исправьте ответ, чтобы другие читатели не вводились лишний раз в заблуждение =)

Comment: Спасибо, за комментарий!